# Django: Passing request to my modely.py

Tags: django

in order to generate the full url in the email I send to the ticket purchaser, I have to access get_current_site in my models.py. To do so I pass request like this: get_absolute_url(request)

Is there anything wrong in doing it that way, or would you consider this as good code/approach?

```
def checkout_page(request):
    [...]
                #Send email
                subject = render_to_string('checkout/email/your_ticket_subject.txt', {})
                to_email = [transaction_profile.cleaned_data['email'],]
                email_ticket_link = t.get_absolute_url(request, email=True)
                content = render_to_string('checkout/email/your_ticket_message.txt', {'email_ticket_link': email_ticket_link,})
                send_mail(subject, content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to_email)

                ticket_link = t.get_absolute_url(request)
                return redirect(ticket_link)
```

**models.py**

```
class TicketPurchase(models.Model):
    order               = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #change CASCADE
    ticket              = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #change CASCADE
    ticketpurchase_id   = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    refunded            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self, request, email=False):
        ticket_link = reverse("ticketsgenerator:show_tickets",
                            kwargs={"order_id": self.order.order_id, "customer_key": self.order.customer_key}
                        )           
        if email:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            return 'https://{}{}'.format(current_site, ticket_link)
        return ticket_link
```

Comment: why you send the request there? [*When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) you can't access request there... you don't need it either to generate the `get_absolute_url`

Comment: Hi @Lemayzeur, the reason I need request is to call get_current_site(request) in my models.py. Does this make sense?